How to use field accessor on a Record to retrieve field name as string
Given the following record:
public record TestRecord(int age, String name)

How to retrieve name field name string using TestRecord::name field accessor?
The final usage would be to be able to have a dynamic properties mapper to convert an object to a DTO using Jackson's objectMapper such as:
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleDTOMapper mapper = new SimpleDTOMapper(objectMapper);

Map<Function<OutputDTO, ?>, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(OutputDTO::field1, objectList);
properties.put(OutputDTO::field2, longField);
properties.put(OutputDTO::field3, false);
properties.put(OutputDTO::field4, longField);

OutputDTO outputDto = mapper.extendDto(inputDto, OutputDTO.class, properties);

My current `extendDto` method and related class are as such:
public class SimpleDTOMapper {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public SimpleDTOMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public <I, O> O extendDto(I inputDto, Class<O> outputDtoClass, Map<Function<O, ?>, Object> properties) {
        Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(inputDto, Map.class);
        
        for (Map.Entry<Function<O, ?>, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = getFieldName(entry.getKey());
            map.put(fieldName, entry.getValue());
        }

        return objectMapper.convertValue(map, outputDtoClass);
    }

    private <T, R> String getFieldName(Function<T, R> getter) {
        Method method = getter.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0];
        return method.getName();
    }
}

getDeclaredMethod()[0] returns a lambda generated name, and not the method name from the accessor.
If not possible, how could I get this field name without using any string litteral to reference to it?
I've tried reflection using writeReplace etc... To no avail.
